# how to rotate an textfield with pan gesture?

Tags: objective-c, ios, rotation, xcode4.3, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm thinking of possibilities if i can use a pan gesture to rotate an textfield to make much smoother rotation. can you please help me?please.

**Update:**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer.h


    @interface KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer 
    {

    }

    /**
     The rotation of the gesture in radians since its last change.
     */
    @property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat rotation;

    @end



    KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer.m

    #import "KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer.h"
    #import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>


    @implementation KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer

    @synthesize rotation = rotation_;

    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
       // Fail when more than 1 finger detected.
       if ([[event touchesForGestureRecognizer:self] count] > 1) {
          [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed];
       }
    }

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
       if ([self state] == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible) {
          [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan];
       } else {
          [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged];
       }

       // We can look at any touch object since we know we 
       // have only 1. If there were more than 1 then 
       // touchesBegan:withEvent: would have failed the recognizer.
       UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

       // To rotate with one finger, we simulate a second finger.
       // The second figure is on the opposite side of the virtual
       // circle that represents the rotation gesture.

       UIView *view = [self view];
       CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX([view bounds]), CGRectGetMidY([view bounds]));
       CGPoint currentTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:view];
       CGPoint previousTouchPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:view];

       CGFloat angleInRadians = atan2f(currentTouchPoint.y - center.y, currentTouchPoint.x - center.x) - atan2f(previousTouchPoint.y - center.y, previousTouchPoint.x - center.x);

       [self setRotation:angleInRadians];
    }

    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
       // Perform final check to make sure a tap was not misinterpreted.
       if ([self state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
          [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded];
       } else {
          [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed];
       }
    }

    - (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
       [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed];
    }
```

on my view controller

```
   - (IBAction)handleRotate:(KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {    
    NSLog(@"Rotation");

    choosePhotoView = [recognizer view];
    [choosePhotoView setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate([choosePhotoView transform], [recognizer rotation])];
    [choosePhotoView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0)];

}
```

Comment: Hi just google out this..... http://rogchap.com/2011/06/10/ios-image-manipulation-with-uigesturerecognizer-scale-move-rotate/

Comment: thanks. but I want to try one finger rotation using pan gesture?

Comment: Hi pls go through this links and google out http://blog.mellenthin.de/archives/2012/02/13/an-one-finger-rotation-gesture-recognizer/     https://github.com/kirbyt/KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer

Comment: thanks. I'm trying to apply kirbyt/KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer on my work but it is not working.it doesn't apply the rotation.

Comment: Can you please post the code which you have tried till now for this?

Comment: with UIView animation you may make it much smoother.

Comment: I am not sure about KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer. Have you checked the sample code provided, and is there any difference from that code to this. I am not sure about [choosePhotoView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0)]; also. Try with different angles.

Comment: the code @Spynet say to check out, i used kirbyt/KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer, but apparently when i apply it to my code it doesn't work i even put Nslog to know if is working but it is still not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider `UITextField` as `UIView` and apply the suitable `transform`. You will get a lot of sample codes from net. You need to set the `textfield.transform` property for the same.